# React native give object a name in array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, object, arraylist

My array looks like this:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "color": "Brown",
    "time": "18:32",
  },
  Object {
    "color": "Red",
    "time": "18:33",
  },
]
```

But how can I change Object to a name?

I push it like this

```
const itemLogs = [];

childSnapshot.forEach((csh) => {
let childKeys = csh.key;
itemLogs.push({
    color:   csh.val().color,
    time:   csh.val().time
});
});
this.setState({childData: itemLogs});
```

UPDATE:

This is how I would like to have it:

```
10-05-2019 [
  14:27 {
    "color": "Brown",
    "time": "14:27",
  },
  14:23 {
    "color": "Red",
    "time": "14:23",
  },
],
11-06-2019 [
like above but other data
]
```

I hope this is an better Example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debugger visualizes your data like this:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "color": "Brown",
    "time": "18:32",
  },
  Object {
    "color": "Red",
    "time": "18:33",
  },
]
```

But it actually looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "color": "Brown",
    "time": "18:32",
  },
  {
    "color": "Red",
    "time": "18:33",
  },
]
```

You can add a `name` property to your objects with:

```
itemLogs.push({
    color:   csh.val().color,
    time:   csh.val().timem,
    name: 'YOUR_NAME_GOES_HERE'
});
```

Then your data would look like this:

```
[
  {
    "color": "Brown",
    "time": "18:32",
    "name": "YOUR_FIRST_NAME",
  },
  {
    "color": "Red",
    "time": "18:33",
    "name": "YOUR_SECOND_NAME",
  },
]
```

**Updated solution:**

```js
const itemLogs = {}; //create an object

var arr = []; // create a temporary array 
var tmp = {}; //create a temporary object 
 tmp["14:27"] = {
    "color": "Brown",
    "time": "14:27",
  }; 

arr.push(tmp); // add object to array 


var tmp2 = {}; //create another tmp object
 tmp2["14:23"] = {
   "color": "Red",
    "time": "14:23",
  }; 
arr.push(tmp2); // add object to array 
itemLogs["10-05-2019"] = arr; // add the array to itemLogs with new key

console.log(itemLogs);
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, but I have multiple childs in my database so I would love to have it in multiple layers. I will update my code so you will understand it better.

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly fine now! I will post the answere here.

Comment: do you also know how to show the data? I'm trying to use map or flatlist but I can't get it working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56098693/show-all-the-data-from-a-nested-array-of-objects-in-react-native here it is.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tim

```
let userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    firebase.database().ref('table/' + userId).on('value', (snapshot) => {
        const itemLogs = {};
        const tmp = {};
        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
            childSnapshot.forEach((csh) => {

                tmp[csh.key] = {
                    color:   csh.val().color,
                    time:   csh.val().time
                };
            });
            itemLogs[childSnapshot.key] = tmp;
            console.log(itemLogs);
        });
    });
```

Now it looks like this:

```
    Object {
  "11-5-2019": Object {
    "18:32": Object {
      "color": "Brown",
      "time": "18:32",
    },
    "18:33": Object {
      "color": "Red",
      "time": "18:33",
    },
  },
}
```