# Show all the data from a nested array of objects in React Native

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, arraylist, multidimensional-array

This is my data in a state called childData: {}

```
Object {
  "11-5-2019": Object {
    "18:32": Object {
      "color": "Brown",
      "time": "18:32",
    },
    "18:33": Object {
      "color": "Red",
      "time": "18:33",
    },
  },
}
```

I want to show all this data on one page. I've tried to use a map but it gives me an error. Also I have tried a FlatList.

```
{this.childData.map(item, index =>
<View key={index}>
    <Text>{item}</Text>
</View>
)}
```

But I don't know how to get all the data.
I want to have the data like this in text:

```
11-05-2019
  18:32
    brown
    18:32
  18:33
    red
    18:33
```

Comment: I answered your question below, if you have any questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `.map` and `FlatList` are expecting an array. You are passing an object. So first you need to make that you are passing an array.

You can do that by using [lodash](https://lodash.com/):

Install lodash with:

```
npm i --save lodash
```

and then use it with:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
```

Now we can transform your data within the render function :

```
render() {
   //get all keys, we pass them later 
   const keys = Object.keys(YOUR_DATA_OBJECTS);
   //here we are using lodah to create an array from all the objects
   const newData = _.values(YOUR_DATA_OBJECTS);
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <FlatList
        data={newData}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => this.renderItem(item, keys[index])}
       />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

And now we have two helper render functions:

```
  renderSmallItems(item){
    console.log('small item', item);
    // iterate over objects, create a new View and return the result
    const arr = _.map(item, function(value, key) {
    return (
        <View key={key}>
          <Text> Color:  {value.color} </Text>
          <Text> Time:  {value.time} </Text>
        </View>
    );
  });
     return arr; 
  }
  renderItem(item, key) {
    return(
      <View style={{marginBottom: 15}}>
      <Text> Key: {key} </Text>
      {this.renderSmallItems(item)}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

**Output:**

[image: demo image]

**Working Demo:**

https://snack.expo.io/HyBSpYr2E